# How to create custom IBActions in a custom class?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I'm creating a new class - UIMyTextView that inherits from UITextView.

I'd like this class to send new kinds of events, that I will then connect using IBuilder to the appropriate IBActions.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITextView` does not inherit from `UIControl`. This means that it can't be considered as UI control that can send actions to other responders using `UIControlEvent`.

See UIControl.h for more information.